How can I dynamically load doctors based on the selected department in Flask?
I'm working on a Flask application where users can schedule appointments. In my application, I have a form where users can select a department and then choose a doctor from that department. How do I load doctors dynamically. I actually need to send it to flask without changing the page, which was not available in other answers

hasta_randevual.html HTML File:
<form action="/randevual/{{ hasta_id }}" method="POST">
    <label for="department">Bölüm:</label>
    <select id="department" name="department" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Bölüm Seçiniz</option>
        <option value="Genel Cerrahi">Genel Cerrahi</option>
        <option value="Kardiyoloji">Kardiyoloji</option>
        <!-- Other department options -->
    </select>

    <label for="doctor">Doktor:</label>
    <select id="doctor" name="doctor" required>
        {% for doktor in doktorlar %}
            <option value="{{ doktor[0] }}">{{ doktor[1] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Randevu Al</button>
</form>

app.py Python File:
@app.route("/randevual/<hasta_id>")
def randevu_al(hasta_id):
    doktorlar=[]
    bolum_sec = request.form.get('department')
    if request.method == "POST":
        if bolum_sec:
            doktorlar = Doktor.doktor_bolgoster(bolum_sec)
    return render_template("hasta_randevual.html", hasta_id=hasta_id, doktorlar = doktorlar)


The duplicate list has been updated, as similar questions and answers already addressed your issue. This answer gives a sufficient overview of what you need, and this answer also provides a single file flask application.
